# Accessing an element in django (for)

Tags: javascript, css, django, templates

I have a Django template with the following code which creates multiple buttons and tries to hide/show description text on a click (on the same button in each card):

```
{% for comida in comidas %}


            {% if comida.slug_food == page.slug  %}
            <div class="food2">
                <div id="food-title">{{comida.titulo}}</div>
                <div id="food-price">{{comida.precio|floatformat:"-1"}}€</div>
                <button class="button" onclick="showDescription()">ver+
                <div id="food-description" >
                {{comida.descripcion|safe}}
                </div>
                </button>
                
                <div id="add-cart">AÑADIR AL PEDIDO</div>

                {% if comida.imagen != null %}
                    <img src="{{comida.imagen.url}}"></img>
                {% endif %}

            </div>

            
                {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}
```

where comidas is a list of strings, and later in the script block I have

```
function showDescription(){
    var showText = document.getElementById("food-description");
    if (showText.style.display === "block"){
        showText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        showText.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

The function runs, but as you may expect, it runs only on the first element of my for loop.

My question is ¿anyone can help me? i want work all my buttons and not only the first element.

Comment: because the id's are same for the second element which conflicts ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{{comida.id}}` to get unique ids :

```html
{% for comida in comidas %}

    {% if comida.slug_food == page.slug  %}
    <div class="food2">
        <div id="food-title">{{comida.titulo}}</div>
        <div id="food-price">{{comida.precio|floatformat:"-1"}}€</div>
        <button class="button" onclick="showDescription('{{comida.id}}')">ver+
        <div id="food-description-{{comida.id}}" >
        {{comida.descripcion|safe}}
        </div>
        </button>
        
        <div id="add-cart">AÑADIR AL PEDIDO</div>

        {% if comida.imagen != null %}
            <img src="{{comida.imagen.url}}"></img>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
    {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

And javascript :

```js
function showDescription(comidaId){
    var showText = document.getElementById("food-description-" + comidaId);
    if (showText.style.display === "block"){
        showText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        showText.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```